# Why this program is not working?

Tags: java, loops, debugging, if-statement, while-loop

I'm trying to write a program  to sum all the integers between 1 and 1000, that are divisible by 13, 15 or 17, but not by 30. The code i tried is given below. I'm getting in a loop which prints sum=0 again and again forever. Please help!

```
package project;

    public class div13n15n17not30 {

    int sum=0;

    int num=0;


    while(num<=1000){

        if(num%13==0||num%15==0||num%17==0 ){

        if(num%30!=0){
            sum=sum+num;
        ++num;
        }
        }

        System.out.println("Sum = "+sum);   
        }

    }
    }
```

Comment: your code can´t print anything because it just appears inside of the class and not in a function. This code wont compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

at first you should put your code inside a function. For this example a simple main would be enough. What you did wrong is, you tried counting until `1000`, but only increased your counter value when you´d increase your sum.

you should do it after each iteration

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int sum = 0;
    int num = 0;
    while (num <= 1000) {
        if (num % 13 == 0 || num % 15 == 0 || num % 17 == 0) {
            if (num % 30 != 0) {
                sum = sum + num;
            }
        }
        // increase num here.
        ++num;
    }
    System.out.println("Sum = " + sum);

}
```

But i´d look a bit smoother if you´d be using a `for` instead of a `while` loop.
The `for` loop just fits better here.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int sum = 0;
    for(int num = 0;num <= 1000;++num) {
        if (num % 13 == 0 || num % 15 == 0 || num % 17 == 0) {
            if (num % 30 != 0) {
                sum = sum + num;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Sum = " + sum);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the modulus operator % to determine if it's divisible by that number exactly; a modulus of 0 means that it's exactly divisible. So you can do:

```
while(num<=1000) {
  if(num%13==0||num%15==0||num%17==0 ){
    if(num%30!=0){
      sum=sum+num;
    }
  }
  num++;
  System.out.println("Sum = "+sum);   
}
```

Comment: No it isn't at the wrong place, it's just bad format...

Answer (score 0):

You can use only one if

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
     int sum = 0;
        for(int num = 0;num <= 1000;++num) {
            if ((num % 13 == 0 || num % 15 == 0 || num % 17 == 0)&& (num % 30 != 0)) {
                    sum = sum + num;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Sum = " + sum);
    }
```

Comment: I think I can use more than one if or nested ifs.

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int sum = 0;

    int num = 0;

    while (num <= 1000) {

        if (num % 13 == 0 || num % 15 == 0 || num % 17 == 0) {

            if (num % 30 != 0) {
                System.out.println("here" + num);
                sum = sum + num;
            }
        }
        ++num;

    }
    System.out.println("Sum = " + sum);

}
```